# Invalid hook call when using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I get this error when trying to dispatch an action from my react functional component:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

This React component does not render anything just listen to keypress event on the page

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const {
  actions: { moveDown }
} = gameSlice;

type Props = {};

export const Keyboard = ({}: Props) => {
  useEffect(() => document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) => dispatch(moveDown())));
  return <></>;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `const dispatch = useDispatch();` into the component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the TypeScript typings for functional components, and provide the props as part of the generic typings. And don't forget to import the required modules.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

type Props = {};

export const Keyboard: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  useEffect(() => document.addEventListener('keydown', ({ keyCode }) => dispatch(moveDown())));
  return <></>;
};
```